# SQL query to select combination of 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

We have external columns (python tuples) which represent workers ids and id of their shifts at consturction site. We need to select rows from SQL table where user_id and shift_id are both in those tuples.

Below are examples reduced to 3 elements:

```
Tuple_user_id = (1,2,3) 
Tuple_shift_id = (A11,A12,A13)
```

So there should be only column combinations 1-A11, 2-A12, 3-A13.The request is:

```
SELECT * FROM user_shift_actions 
WHERE user_id IN Tuple_user_id AND shift_id IN Tuple_shift_id
```

But it returns exessive column combinations like 1- A13, 2-A11.
How this request can be changes to avoid the problem?

Note that Each tuple lengh is 250 elements, so it cannot be done by manually mathcing combinations.

Comment: You can use `SELECT * FROM user_shift_actions WHERE find_in_set(user_id,Typlle_user_id) = find_in_set(shift_id, Tuple_shift_id);` (see [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set))

Comment: What is `Tuple_user_id` and `Tuple_shift_id` in your sql code? Are they comma separated strings?

Comment: Yes, it looks like (1,2,3) and (A11,A12,A13). All thing are done in python and those values come from different non-SQL table.

Comment: would it be possible to have the input (user_id, shift_id) as a temp table and then join based on both the keys ?

Comment: What do you mean it *looks like...*? Post your Python code to clarify.

Comment: data_uss = get_dataframe(host=host_actions, user_name=user_name_actions, password=password_actions,
                                  db_name=db_name_actions, port=port_actions, sql_request=f"""SELECT * FROM user_shift_actions 
                                  WHERE user_id IN {tuple(df['user_id'].values)} AND shift_id IN {tuple(df['shift_id'].values)};""")

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `OR` in your where clause

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    user_shift_actions
WHERE
    (user_id = 1 AND shift_id = A11)
    OR (user_id = 2 AND shift_id = A12)
    OR (user_id = 3 AND shift_id = A13)
```

OR with `IN` clause

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    user_shift_actions
WHERE
    (user_id, shift_id) IN ((1, A11), (2, A12), (3, A13))
```

OR by creating a link table like

```sql
WITH user_shift_link AS (
    SELECT 1 as user_id, 'A11' AS shift_id
    UNION SELECT 1, 'A12'
    UNION SELECT 1, 'A13'
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    user_shift_actions
INNER JOIN user_shift_link
  ON user_shift_actions.user_id = user_shift_link.user_id
  AND user_shift_actions.shift_id = user_shift_link.shift_id
```

Comment: Unfrotunately those tuples are large

Comment: @NikitaTsekhanovich unfortunately, this is the correct answer! Alternative would be saving the tuples as rows in a temporary table and doing an inner join.

Comment: What is "large"?  Please edit the question to show what you actually need

Comment: 250 + elements. Changed, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Sorry but as Shadow said, there are no 1000 answers, I just add his solution but after this..